# Notepad++ Reverse Text by Column?

Tags: notepad++

I need help with Notepad++

Here I have a Text List:

```
King7|Dave555
```

but i need

Example:

```
Dave555|King7
```

How to change position in Notepad++?

Answer (score 2):

Do a Find/Replace.

- Find what: `^(.*)|(.*)$`
- Replace with: `\2|\1`
- Search mode: Regular expression

This will search for the beginning of the line, followed by any number of characters, followed by a pipe, followed by any number of characters, followed by the end of the line. It will replace it with the second group of characters, followed by a pipe, followed by the first group of characters.

Comment: maybe "everything minus pipe" for the first part?

Comment: That would be `^([^|]*)|([^|]*)$`. I didn't do that initially because `.*` is easier to type & to remember than `[^|]*`, and `.*` accomplishes what it needs to.